Select option agents user interface Anylogic
I'm grappling with what seems to be a rather intricate issue and unfortunately, I haven't come across any examples to guide me.
Here's the situation: I have a group of agents (Dosings), each with its own distinct dosing name as parameter. Now, during runtime, I need to be able to choose which dosings I want to include or exclude from my simulation, possibly using checkboxes or a similar interface.
For instance, let's say I want to compute the average dosing time, but only for 10 out of the 100 dosings. In this case, I'd like to be able to select these 10 dosings using checkboxes and then calculate their average dosing time using a function or some other method (the function itself isn't the issue).
What I'm looking for is a straightforward approach to display a list or some other representation of all the parameters of my agents, allowing me to dynamically select which ones to include or exclude during runtime. I'm aiming to avoid manually creating a variable and displaying it in the user interface; instead, I'm seeking a more robust solution.
Thanks,
Aron

filter your agents by its parameters... findAll(...) or similar. Or create replicated checkboxes... there are tons of ways, depends on the details and your skill level. Better describe what you have, what you tried and boil it down to a simple setup, not the broad  question here... see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow
